# SSH Service Restart error after changing ssh port listen

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch

I changed what port my raspberry pi was listening on, as I'm currently blocked from adding a rule on my router for port 22.

I did `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

and changed `#port 22` to `port 2234` (removing the #)

I then tried to restart the service through `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart` and got a failed status.

I tried checking the status through  `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh` status

and I got

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-04-02 18:00:04 CDT; 12min a
  Process: 474 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)

Apr 02 18:00:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell ser
Apr 02 18:00:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 02 18:00:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over,
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too 
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell ser
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
lines 1-14/14 (END)...skipping...
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-04-02 18:00:04 CDT; 12min ago
  Process: 474 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)

Apr 02 18:00:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 02 18:00:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 02 18:00:03 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 02 18:00:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any suggestions how to get sshd running again?

Comment: please try the suggestion in the error message `Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full` that way you'll see the error in full - because `Failed with result 'exi…e'` means next to nothing

Comment: @JaromandaX edited original post

Comment: If you change it back, does it work?

Comment: just tried. Weirdly doesnt. i get Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: so, it's not working - perhaps you broke something in your original edit

Comment: my config has `Port 22` not commented for a start, and a capital P

Comment: my config originally had it commented, and i appologize it was Port 22. I enabled SSH before someone asks

Comment: No need to apologise, thought it may have been significant - and you say it doesn't work even if you revert the config back to its original state?

Comment: does running `sudo sshd -t` help with diagnosing the issue (-t is apparently test mode)

Answer (score 2):

that's not the right way to restart it. Use
`systemctl restart ssh.service`